# Why is my task failing in Google's App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, cron-task, app.yaml

About 3-4 times a week one of my two 12hr tasks that acts as an ETL from an API endpoint to a Snowflake DB fails and I can't figure out exactly why.

The Cron Task Mananger says it last ran at 6:29am this morning but in retrieving the logs there's only one line which says:

```
This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This request may thus take longer and use more CPU than a typical request for your application.
```

I'm not sure if I need a warm-up, allocate specific workers, etc. because the log of the one-line error is so uninformative to me. I'm using a pretty sizable instance class I was hoping could handle most the workload.

Here is what the logs of a successful run look like:

https://github.com/markamcgown/GF/blob/main/downloaded-logs-success2.csv

And the failure:

https://github.com/markamcgown/GF/blob/main/downloaded-logs-20210104-074656.csv

App.yaml:

```
service: vetdata-loader
runtime: python38

instance_class: F4_1G

handlers:

- url: /task/loader
  script: auto
```

Updated, here is my most recent app.yaml that's failing less now but still sometimes:

```
service: vetdata-loader
runtime: python38

instance_class: B4_1G

handlers:

- url: /task/loader
  script: auto

basic_scaling:
  max_instances: 11
  idle_timeout: 30m
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you don't use the correct instance class. If you have a look [here about the timeouts and the task call](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-appengine-handlers#timeouts) you are limited to 10 minutes call for automatic scaling, and up to 24h with basic and manual scaling.

If I take your `instance_class`, the FXXX type is [suitable for automatic scaling](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard#instance_classes). Use a `B4_1G` instance class instead and check if you still have these issues. You should not.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that. Can you describe why I just get one line of the error log for my failure if it is timing out after 10 minutes? I thought I'd see it run and output what I see when I run it for up to 10 minutes before I originally deploy it. Does it have to do with it not being warmed up and is there a way to see logs related to what's really going on for those potential 10min?

Comment: I agree, the 1 line logs is not normal, you should start the processing and stop after few minutes. The warning line is normal if you scale from 0. Do you have a view on Cloud Logging? You might have more detail.

Comment: Hey guillaume, I made you changes and it stopped failing as often but after 3 days (6 runs) it still had a failure, again with the same 1-line log. Can you take a look at my updated app.yaml above and give any final thoughts on how to better tweak it, perhaps aside from a higher timeout/instances? I'll try that and give you credit for your answer if so since it it sort of helping but not fully yet.

Comment: And you still have 1 line of logs? No more in Cloud Logging?

Comment: Yes, just the one line oddly. I don't know any way to relay that to Google, either, without paying, or just general feedback.

Comment: I did it, I pushed your question of Googler with App Engine experience. We will see...